# How can I manipulate a part of a text depending of the sign of a parameter or the parameter itself (automated calculation solution quadratic function)

Tags: pgfmath

I want to make a complete solution sheet with the whole context for my students.

My code is this (with the answer I changed my problem) to this:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\TGFT}[3]{
% input variabelen
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{#3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\D}{\b^2-4*\a*\c}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XI}{(-\b+sqrt(\D))/(2*\a)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XII}{(-\b-sqrt(\D))/(2*\a)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\P}{-\b/(2*\a)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Q}{(4*\a*\c-\b^2)/(4*\a)}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $D= \D$
    \item $x_1= \XI$
    \item $x_2= \XII$
    \item $f(x)=\a x\checksign{\b} x \checksign{\c}$
    \item $p=\P$
    \item $q=\Q$
    \item $f(x)=\a(x-\checksign{\XI})(x-\checksign{\XII})$
\end{itemize}
}

\newcommand\checksign[1]{\expandafter\checksignaux#1\relax\relax}
\def\checksignaux#1#2{\ifx-#1\relax#1#2\else+#1#2\fi}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \TGFT{1}{5}{6}
    \item \TGFT{2}{2}{-12}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]
My questions are:

- how can I make it (exercise 2) writing f(x) =2x^2+2x-12 and NOT +-12
- How can I display the numbers in a fraction (if possible)
- How can I display the numbers like 1 and NOT 1.0 (so no extra zero's, just the number)

Or is their a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps `sagetex` can solve all current and all subsequent problems.

Comment: @Symbol1 thanks for the help, but it could make me display my calculated items as a fraction

Comment: SageMath, the exterior program that hides behind `sagetex`, is a serious math program that can calculate, say, polynomials with rational coefficients. It can also factorize or expand polynomials (over any given ring) without you worrying about + and -.

Comment: @Symbol1 Ok, I will try to study the package :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented in a follow up, I have introduced `\showsign` to retain the current sign of what follows or `\switchsign` to reverse it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\TGFT}[3]{
% input variabelen
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{#3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\D}{\b^2-4*\a*\c}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XI}{(-\b+sqrt(\D))/(2*\a)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XII}{(-\b-sqrt(\D))/(2*\a)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\P}{-\b/(2*\a)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Q}{(4*\a*\c-\b^2)/(4*\a)}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $D= \D$
    \item $x_1= \XI$
    \item $x_2= \XII$
    \item $f(x)=\a x\showsign{\b} x \showsign{\c}$
    \item $p=\P$
    \item $q=\Q$
    \item $f(x)=\a(x \switchsign{\XI})(x \switchsign{\XII})$
\end{itemize}
}

\newcommand\showsign[1]{\expandafter\showsignaux#1\relax\relax}
\def\showsignaux#1#2{\ifx-#1\relax#1#2\else+#1#2\fi}
\newcommand\switchsign[1]{\expandafter\switchsignaux#1\relax\relax}
\def\switchsignaux#1#2{\ifx-#1\relax+#2\else-#1#2\fi}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \TGFT{1}{5}{6}
    \item \TGFT{2}{2}{-12}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Problem  is solved when I have +- but not when it's something like - -. (I will adapt my question

Comment: @ArneTimperman I have `\showsign` to retain the current sign or `\switchsign` to reverse it.